# Are these two bash snippets equivalent and if not which is better?

Tags: bash, sh

I am interested on which is better in the sense of either being more flexible/general/extensible or faster or less error prone or uses less memory.

Snippet1:

```
grep '^+[^+]' /tmp/p0rn.lst | while read x;do
    wget $x
done
```

Snippet2:

```
while read x;do
    wget $x
done < <(grep '^+[^+]' /tmp/p0rn.lst)
```

Comment: They're equivalent *here*, but a) both should quote `$x`, and b) the first one is more likely to lead to [BashFAQ/024](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: In terms of performance/memory/file IO, it would come down to *how* process sustitutions are implemented. I don't know.

Comment: Just would like to point out, that the `flexibility` or `extensibility` that i meant is when doing impromptu `kinetic` scripting real time in the command line during a days work. In this regard, I find the use of  `|` wins here because we usually do a `grep` first and then through an iterative process we pipe more operations succeedingly to the right as we tune and re-tune our intents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first uses a pipeline, the second process substitution. Process substitution is usually better.

Piping input to a loop means the loop runs in a subshell. **Variable changes inside a subshell are lost** when the subshell finishes, i.e. when the loop ends.

For example, if you wanted to count the number of URLs processed by incrementing a variable each iteration you'd have to use process substitution:

```
count=0

while read x; do
    wget "$x"
    ((++count))
done < <(grep '^+[^+]' /tmp/p0rn.lst)

echo "processed $count urls"
```

If you used a pipeline it would always print "processed 0 urls":

```
count=0

grep '^+[^+]' /tmp/p0rn.lst | while read x; do
    wget "$x"
    ((++count))
done

# Doesn't work!
echo "processed $count urls"
```

Comment: Note that before Bash version 4.4 there was no direct way to get the exit status of a command run in a process substitution.  See the 'Pitfalls' section of [ProcessSubstitution - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) for more information. Even with Bash 4.4 there are limitations (e.g. if two process substitutions are used in a single command).

Comment: The pipeline code can be made to work in Bash 4.2+ by preceding it with `shopt -s lastpipe`.  See [BashFAQ/024 - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @john-kugelman 's answer I would like to point out that the `bash` holds a variable called `PIPESTATUS` which is an array of all the exit codes of the last pipe:

```
(exit 1) | (exit 2) | (exit 3) | (exit 4); echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
```

This will print

```
1 2 3 4
```

There is no similar mechanism if this is rewritten using process substitutions:

```
(exit 4) < <(
  (exit 3) < <(
    (exit 2) < <(
      (exit 1)
    )
  )
)
```

In this case, the inner exit codes are just lost, unless they are *explicitly* stored somehow (e. g. dumped in a file or similar).

The *overall* exit code of a pipe is the exit code of the last pipe element, on default, so `true | false` is like `false`.  In many cases this is desirable, e. g.

```
if curl "$url" | grep -q "searchterm"
then
  # do something in case the searchterm was found
```

In this usage the exit value of the `grep` clearly is what is wanted.

There are other uses, however, in which you would rather react on the exit value of the left element:

```
curl "$url" | sed 's/password.*/###/g' > x || {  # incorrect usage!
  echo "Curl failed." 1>&2
}
```

This will not work because the pipe's exit value is the exit value of `sed` (which in this case is not the relevant part).  Moving the check deeper inside can solve the issue:

```
(
  curl "$url" || echo "Curl failed." 1>&2
) | sed 's/password.*/###/g' > x
```

Or also:

```
sed 's/password.*/###/g' < <(
  curl "$url" || echo "Curl failed." 1>&2
) > x
```

But neither allows e. g. exiting the surrounding shell properly (because the check is done in a nested scope).

You can, however, use the `pipefail` option of the shell in which case a pipe's exit value is the exit value of the rightmost non-zero exit value:

```
set -o pipefail
(exit 1) | (exit 2) | (exit 3) | (exit 0); echo $?
```

This will print `3` instead of `0`.  Applied to our last example:

```
set -o pipefail
if ! curl "$url" | sed 's/password.*/###/g' > x
then
  echo "Curl failed (or sed)." 1>&2
  # Now we can even exit this shell here if we like.
fi
```

(You might want to scope the `pipefail` option to avoid influencing the rest of the script.)

You can, however, achieve a similar thing using process substitutions for the *output*:

```
if ! curl "$url" > >(sed 's/password.*/###/g' > x)
then
  echo "Curl failed." 1>&2
  # Now we can even exit this shell here if we like.
fi
```

But this will ignore failures in the right commands of the pipe (`sed` in this case).  Using `pipefail` you can react on failures in *any* of the piped commands.  There is no (simple and recommendable) way of achieving this using process substitutions.